# How to fetch image in Roku BrightScript?

Tags: roku, brightscript

The below Curl returns an image. I am struggling to find Roku equivalent code to fetch an image and display it in poster node.

```
curl -X GET \
  https://xiorchestrate-xos-svc.prod.ocean.com:8443/xos/users/ocean-cf0183fb-9e93-4964-859b-XXXXXX/photos/profile \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer XXXXX-9024-44b4-8552-d7d799ec00c8' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

`Poster` nodes implement the [ifHttpAgent](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifHttpAgent) interface therefor you should be able to use the [SetHeaders(nameValueMap as Object)](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifHttpAgent#ifHttpAgent-SetHeaders(nameValueMapasObject)asBoolean) function before setting the `uri` to the poster.

```
m.poster = m.top.createChild("Poster")
m.poster.SetHeaders({"Authorization": "Bearer XXXXX-9024-44b4-8552-d7d799ec00c8", ...})
m.poster.uri = "https://xiorchestrate-xos-svc.prod.ocean.com:8443/xos/users/ocean-cf0183fb-9e93-4964-859b-XXXXXX/photos/profile"
```

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely try this and will let you know.

Comment: Glad it worked! Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you .

Answer (score 0):

You need to make poster node for implementing the image in roku.
Create a poster node with `<poster />` tag with id and other things like width and height and tranlation, etc,. in xml.
After creating the poster node you need to find the node using id with Findnode method in the brs file, like `m.poster_id = m.top.findnode("poster_id")` here m.poster_id is the glbal variable we initialize for using it for performing another operations.
Now, time to set the image uri into the poster node: `m.poster_id.uri = "images/image1.png"`